# Are requests for an emergency landing ever refused?

Tags: air-traffic-control, aviation-history, emergency, emergency-procedures

Under what circumstances might it happen that a pilot's request to make an emergency landing is refused?

Is such a thing known to have occurred?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on History.SE rather than Aviation.

Comment: @RalphJ I disagree, we plenty of questions on here that could overlap with History.SE and this is very much a question specific to the aviation field.

Comment: @RalphJ sooo..... emergency landings arent part of aviation?

Comment: @RalphJ This seems solidly on-topic to me, since it's about "flying technique, maneuvers, navigation, procedures, etc.", Air Traffic Control, and aviation regulations. Can you explain why it's off-topic in your opinion?

Comment: @TannerSwett  No, this question isn't about any of those things at all. It asks "has (this) ***ever*** happened, what was the outcome, and was it legal?"  Those are history-book questions, and maybe Law.SE for the last part. How you *conduct* a successful emergency landing is solidly on-topic; did one nation ever (***ever***) deny permission for one back in the Cold War era, is not. Note that the Help Center makes no mention of "aviation history" as on-topic: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @RalphJ I remember a rule in History.SE about "No research then get out!"

Comment: I recall reading about some airline incidents like this in the Middle East, I think in Saudi Arabia.

Comment: @JonathanIrons that rule about doing some basic prior research applies to _every_ site on the SE network, and would definitely be more on topic on History since this is asking for a list of denied emergency landing requests instead of the aviation rules, logistics, or technical limitations/requirements related to doing so.

Comment: @0xdd isnt what I ask considered to be an rule? Wasnt there an international rule about denying emergency rules back in the day?

Comment: Maybe, but that isn't what you're asking -- you are, in the extreme literal sense, asking _whether there were any points_ during the Cold War when an airport denied an aircraft signalling an emergency permission to land. The community can't infer hidden meanings in your questions, and will not try to shoehorn it into something valid on this site. That's up to you.

Comment: @0xdd I actually said I am more interested in Cold War era which made the whole question modeled after it. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Commenters above, the question has now been quite substantially edited. Please review your comments and/or close votes to see if they still apply.

Comment: @DavidRicherby this made me remember my VOR compass question which never got un downvoted...

Comment: @JonathanIrons It's an unfortunate feature of Stack Exchange that downvoters and commenters don't get notified when content changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can imagine a couple of reasons why ATC could tell the pilots to please land somewhere else even if they have an emergency

- All runways are closed, e.g. they are repaving the runway surface or when the snow trucks haven't yet cleared a thick layer of snow or the instrument landing system is inop and the visual conditions are not good enough, runway flooded after hurricane,...
- Another emergency in progress, e.g. passengers freely running around on the airport after an evacuation, not safe to land
- Political reasons with hijacked plane (e.g. Lufthansa Flight 181 Landshut was refused to land even when they declared an emergency with low fuel) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lufthansa_Flight_181
- Presidential no-fly zone when other airports are available close by.
- Virus infected people on board to avoid contamination of those on the ground (zombie apocalypse)

Comment: Last zombie apocalypse, they just asked me if there was anything worth taking in the cargo hold!